# Delphi 10.1 FMX TSpeedButton not resizing to client on Android when StyleLookup set to arrowdowntoolbutton

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have a Multi Device application created in Delphi 10.1 and I'm using a TSpeedButton.

The SpeedButton Align is set to Client.
The SpeedButton StyleLookup is set to arrowdowntoolbutton;

When running in Windows the Speed Button resizes to its bounds.
When running on Android the Speed Button resizes to the size of the image.

How do I get the SpeedButton to behave like it does in Windows i.e. Resize to its bounds?
This is the Form.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 471
  ClientWidth = 354
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object pButtons: TPanel
    Align = Top
    Margins.Left = 5.000000000000000000
    Margins.Top = 1.000000000000000000
    Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
    Position.X = 5.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 1.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 344.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 35.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 4
    object btnSearch: TButton
      Tag = 1
      Align = Right
      StyledSettings = []
      Margins.Left = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 1.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 229.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 114.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 31.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 4
      Text = 'Search'
    end
    object sbtnMore_Search_Options: TSpeedButton
      Align = Client
      Size.Width = 104.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 35.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      StyleLookup = 'arrowdowntoolbutton'
    end
    object btnSpacer: TButton
      Align = Left
      Enabled = False
      Margins.Left = 1.000000000000000000
      Margins.Top = 2.000000000000000000
      Margins.Right = 5.000000000000000000
      Margins.Bottom = 2.000000000000000000
      Position.X = 1.000000000000000000
      Position.Y = 2.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 114.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 31.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 5
    end
  end
end
```

This is the Unit.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    pButtons: TPanel;
    btnSearch: TButton;
    sbtnMore_Search_Options: TSpeedButton;
    btnSpacer: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}


end.
```

Thanks

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. I've published the code. As mentioned the SpeedButton.Align = Client. Therefore the bounds are the client. Again as mentioned SpeedButton.StyleLookup = arrowdowntoolbutton.

Comment: Some controls have a fixed size based on the style (especially on Android). You can use a TRectangle or you can use a helper class to override. See: https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/removing-a-fmx-controls-size-restrictions/